# How to reference System.Data in Visual Studio 2015 targeting .NET Core?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am trying to access the `IDbConnection` interface in a class library in order to make a connection object that connects and fetches data from the database, but I just cannot access the `IDbConnection` interface which was supposed to by in **System.Data.dll**.

I can't find it anywhere in NuGet either. So, how do I go about it?

Has Microsoft changed the way we make connections to a database as well, or is there any new interface introduced in .NET Core?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `IDbConnection`, `IDbCommand` etc. interfaces has been removed from the `System.Data.Common` namespace in .NET Core. They've been replaced by the `DbConnection`, `DbCommand` etc. abstract classes. You can read a discussion on the matter [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/3480).

You can take a look at the .NET Core progress for `System.Data.Common` [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx-progress/blob/d03acd1c88e4de1020f79715e351a8353c758ccd/src-diff/System.Data.Common.md). In the future, if you're uncertain whether types have been moved or removed, this might be a good place to check.

The NuGet package you want to install is [System.Data.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.Common), which contains the mentioned types.

Comment: Thank you. I understand now.