# .net core 2.0, Do not support function GetSchema("Tables")？

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

---

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
conn.Open(); 
var schema = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
```

---

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: **Invalid collection
>   name**. Parameter name: collectionName at
>   MySqlConnector.Core.SchemaProvider.GetSchema(String collectionName) in
>   C:\projects\mysqlconnector\src\MySqlConnector\Core\SchemaProvider.cs:line
>   28

---

But the [web page](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/MetaData.html#getschema) says function GetSchema("Tables") is supportive ：（GetSchema）It is supported only for full .NET Framework, .NET Core 2.0 and higher, or .NET Standard 2.0 or higher.

if net core 2.0 Do not support function GetSchema("Tables")？Is there any other way? thanks very very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37283388/how-do-i-use-system-data-in-a-net-core-rc2-console-app-linux-debian-8
You need to add an dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you might be using [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector). If so, you're running into [issue #375](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector/issues/375) that not all schemas supported by Connector/NET or dotConnect Express for MySQL (Devart) are supported in that connector yet.

If you need them, you'll need to switch connectors (or open a PR to add the feature).